# Sendgrid sg_event_id not sent with all events?

Tags: sendgrid, webhooks

Does anyone know why, when tracking Sendgrid events I don't see sg_event_id in every event? E.g. Open event doesn't have it, yet, Processed and Delivered do.

I was hoping to store events in DynamoDB with sg_event_id as PK, but its not always present...

My research is returning conflicting information:

http://it.toolbox.com/companies/sendgrid/news/event-api-update-new-tracking-parameter-added-74458 - added to the spec

https://github.com/sendgrid/docs/issues/239 - removed from the spec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work for SendGrid.

We haven't finished adding this parameter to every event yet. We had a miscommunication where docs were released before it was fully implemented. Apologies for the trouble!

Comment: Ah, thank you for the answer! Would you be able to say when that update is due to be out fully? Also on a side note, I don't suppose that there is a way of grouping the events generated by the same email?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know when it will be ready, but I will mention it to our team again. For delivery events, you can use the [smtp-id](http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html#-Default-Parameters-for-Delivery-Events) to group events, but that won't help with engagement events.

Comment: Having a unique email ID is needed for us to be able to do stats on times between events - we're working around this limitation by sending our own unique email id, but it would have been handy if SG could give us that data... I'll raise this as a feature request. Thanks for your time!